# Round Register up to multiple of 8

Tags: x86-64, masm

I am trying to round a 64bit register up so it's a multiple of 8. So it ends with either an 8 or 0.

Is there an efficient way to do this, I am currently doing it as follows:

```
xor r9, r9
_R:
    add r9, 08h
    cmp r8, r9
ja _R
mov r8, r9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To round a value up to a multiple of eight requires two statements and *no* loops:

```
add r9, 7
and r9, 0fffffffffffffff8H
```

The first moves any value that's not *already* a multiple of eight into the "next highest section". The second rounds that *down* to a multiple of eight. So you'll get results like:

```
orig  add  and
   0    7    0
   1    8    8
   :    :    :
   7   14    8
   8   15    8
   9   16   16
```

Note that, if you want to round up even those numbers which are *already* multiples of eight (e.g., `8 -> 16`), just add eight instead of seven.

Comment: @Will, suggest you try again, that's handled by the initial `add`: adding seven to `11h` will give you `18h` which will then `and` to `18h`.

Comment: Fun fact: you can write `0xfffffffffffffff8` as `-8`, which is portable to all the x86 assemblers.  For MASM vs. GAS you have to choose between `0xfffffffffffffff8` and `0fffffffffffffff8H` if you want to write it out that way.